# textarea max-width not working inside flex item

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, textarea

I'm using `max-width: 100%` to contain `textarea`. But it doesn't seem to work inside a flex item. Is there a property I can specify on textarea to ensure that the max will be respected?

```
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[See codepen.](https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/YrEqqp) Flex classes from from [flexboxes](https://github.com/ryanve/flexboxes/tree/v0.7.0#classes).

Comment: A flex item, by default, cannot be shorter than the width of its content. An initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. Therefore, your `textarea` with 4000 columns is expanding the flex item. Override the default. Add `min-width: 0` to the item. [**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEPQWY)

Comment: Doing `.flex-initial {max-width: 100%;}` solves the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You specify that the text area should be 4,000 columns wide in the codepen, which is what's causing the issue.

Since the parent is a flex container, it will grow to accommodate the children elements.

Easiest fixes are to:

- set a max width in `px`, `vw`, or another appropriate unit for your textarea.
- use `width` instead of `max-width`, and specify a `max-width` on the parent container, instead
- override the default `min-width: auto` of the parent element, setting it to any other value, i.e. `0`, or `250`
- reduce the columns to something more reasonable, like 250 - or omit them and use `width` instead